# How to display binary search tree in console properly?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to display a BST in console. That's my code (it's a modified version of code found here: [Printing Level Order Binary Search Tree Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186941/printing-level-order-binary-search-tree-formatting)):

```
string printLevel(node *root, int level, string gap) {
  if (!root) {
    return gap + "-" + gap;
  }
  if (level==1) {
    stringstream out;
    out<<root->value;
    return gap + out.str() + gap;
  } else if (level>1) {
    string leftStr = printLevel(root->left, level-1, gap);
    string rightStr = printLevel(root->right, level-1, gap);
    return leftStr + " " + rightStr;
  } else return "";
}

void printLevelOrder (node* root, int depth) {
  for (int i=1; i<=depth; i++) {
    string gap="";
    for (int j=0; j<pow(2,depth-i)-1; j++) {
      gap+=" ";
    }
    string levelNodes = printLevel(root, i, gap);
    cout<<levelNodes<<endl;
  }
}
```

For example result should be like that:

```
       4
   1       6
 -   2   5   - 
- - - 3 - - - -
```

But instead it is:

```
       4       
   1       6
 -   2   5   -
- - 3 - - -
```

If I undestand correctly, the recursion stops when the program makes it to the empty leaf and therefore there are lacking " - " on the lower levels in the result. But how do I know how much of those I should draw on the lower levels? How to make this work?

Comment: You also have an issue with where `3` is displayed, it should be to the right of `2`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's actually bound to the main issue. If the tree was displayed correctly, the `3` would have been on its place. In the means of data structure, it is a right child of the `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I instrumented the code to see where it went awry (since running a debugger in a browser...), you can see it live [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yZGb4%245). The reproduced function is:

```
string printLevel(node *root, int level, string gap) {
  if (root == 0) {
    cout << ".. printLevel - " << root << ": " << gap << "-" << gap << "\n";
    return gap + "-" + gap;
  }
  if (level==1) {
    stringstream out;
    out<<root->value;
    cout << ".. printLevel - " << root << ": " << gap << root->value << gap << "\n";
    return gap + out.str() + gap;
  } else if (level>1) {
    string leftStr = printLevel(root->left, level-1, gap);
    string rightStr = printLevel(root->right, level-1, gap);

    cout << ".. printLevel - " << root << ": '" << leftStr << "', '" << rightStr << "'\n";
    return leftStr + " " + rightStr;
  } else return "";
}
```

And here is the bit of interesting output:

```
.. printLevel - <none>: -
.. printLevel - <none>: -
.. printLevel - { 3, <none>, <none> }: 3
.. printLevel - { 2, <none>, { 3, <none>, <none> } }: '-', '3'
.. printLevel - { 1, <none>, { 2, <none>, { 3, <none>, <none> } } }: '-', '- 3'
```

So, the issue is that you short-circuit whenever `root` is 0, which is actually an issue: `-` is not the right output unless `level` is `1`.

The only difference between `root` being 0 and `root` not being 0 is that you cannot read the value out of it (and thus get to replace it by `-`); however you only really read that value when `level` is `1` (beware, you might try to read `left` or `right` too), therefore there is no reason to test for `root == 0` unless you are in the `level == 1` branch.

Let us slightly reorder things then:

```
string printLevel(node *root, int level, string gap) {
  if (level==1) {
//    if (root == 0) {
//      cout << ".. printLevel - " << root << ": " << gap << "-" << gap << "\n";
//      return gap + "-" + gap;
//    }
    stringstream out;
    out<<root->value;
    cout << ".. printLevel - " << root << ": " << gap << root->value << gap << "\n";
    return gap + out.str() + gap;
  } else if (level>1) {
//    string leftStr = printLevel(root ? root->left : 0, level-1, gap);
//    string rightStr = printLevel(root ? root->right : 0, level-1, gap);

    cout << ".. printLevel - " << root << ": '" << leftStr << "', '" << rightStr << "'\n";
    return leftStr + " " + rightStr;
  } else return "";
}
```

Note: I "highlighted" the modified lines with "comments".

And now, the tree prints properly.

Comment: Now it's working perfectly! Thank you so much for tips and code! Such elegant solution, also thank you for sharing this liveworkspace link, taught me few tricks.

Comment: @raven_raven: liveworkspace (and other online compilers) is a good solution for quick and dirty experiment since we don't have a REPL in C++... and sharing it is so easy!

Answer (score 2):

```
void BinaryTree::Display(TreeNode *current, int indent)
{
    if (current != nullptr)
    {
        Display(current->left, indent + 4);
        if (indent > 0)
            cout << setw(indent) << " ";
        cout << current->value << endl;
        Display(current->right, indent + 4);
    }
}
```

prints tree left to right instead of top down.

```
            1
        2
    3
        4
5
        6
    7
            8
        12
            18
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code. It prints very well,maybe its not perfectly symmetrical.
little description:

- 1st function - prints level by level (root lv -> leaves lv)
- 2nd function - distance from the beginning of new line
- 3rd function - prints nodes and calculates distance between two prints;

---

```
void Tree::TREEPRINT()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= treeHeight(getroot())){
        printlv(i);
        i++;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Tree::printlv(int n){
    Node* temp = getroot();
    int val = pow(2, treeHeight(root) -n+2);
    cout << setw(val) << "";
    prinlv(temp, n, val);
}

void Tree::dispLV(Node*p, int lv, int d)
{
    int disp = 2 * d;
    if (lv == 0){
        if (p == NULL){

            cout << " x ";
            cout << setw(disp -3) << "";
            return;
        }
        else{
            int result = ((p->key <= 1) ? 1 : log10(p->key) + 1);
            cout << " " << p->key << " ";
            cout << setw(disp - result-2) << "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (p == NULL&& lv >= 1){
            dispLV(NULL, lv - 1, d);
            dispLV(NULL, lv - 1, d);
        }
        else{
            dispLV(p->left, lv - 1, d);
            dispLV(p->right, lv - 1, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
50-28-19-30-29-17-42-200-160-170-180-240-44-26-27
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtPXY.png